# Filter in select where values start with NIR_

Tags: sql, sql-server, wildcard, sql-like, startswith

I am trying to filter my result set to only return values which start with `NIR_`.

My SQL statement to do so is as follows

```
select * from run where name like %NIR_%
```

The result set also includes names like

```
NIRMeta_Invalid
NIRMeta_Position
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I only need to select names which start with `NIR_`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the underscore in your `LIKE` pattern if you want it to be treated as a literal.

**In SQL Server:**

```
select * from run where name like 'NIR[_]%'
```

**In MySQL and Oracle:**

```
select * from run where name like 'NIR\_%'
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, i am using SQL server 2014.  Yes the first select statement works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want names that only start with `NIR`, then remove the first wildcard in the `like` pattern:

```
where name like 'NIR_%'
```

Note that `_` is also a wildcard, so you probably want:

```
where name like 'NIR\_%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ESCAPE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) option to achieve this.

```
SELECT * FROM run WHERE name LIKE 'NIR#_%' ESCAPE '#'
```

Sample execution with the given data:

```
DECLARE @Run TABLE (name VARCHAR (100));

INSERT INTO @Run (name) VALUES 
('NIR_MA'), ('NIR_RUN'), ('NIRMeta_Invalid'), ('NIRMeta_Position');

SELECT * FROM @Run WHERE name LIKE 'NIR#_%' ESCAPE '#'
```

Result:

```
name
-----
NIR_MA
NIR_RUN
```